# Is there a C++ implementation of ZIP/unZIP algorithm that supports Unicode file names for Windows?

Tags: c++, unicode, zip

I came across a couple of references to the ZIP/unZIP archiving algorithm using old-style C++ (that was clearly written for ANSI only code.) But now I'm wondering, is there an updated version that supports Unicode file names?

PS. I need this to be written using unmanaged C++.

Comment: What is "old-style C++?"

Comment: using char's instead of TCHAR's or wchars

Comment: That's not a style of C++; that's a style of string usage. Second, there's nothing *old* about that; it's still standard today. TCHARs are a Windows-only thing.

Comment: OK. I called it wrong... this is not the point of this question though.

Comment: Have you tried [Zip Utils](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win32)? It works with VS and Borland C++ compilers and supports Unicode filenames.

Comment: @vulcanraven, +1, it took hardly one minute to find that Zip Utils project.

Comment: @ahmd0: "I called it wrong" Then please edit your question to say what you actually mean.

Comment: @vulcanraven: Your's is technically the answer to my question in despite of all the griping over my asking it. I'm not sure at this point whether it's a Windows bug or if the implementation you pointed to has it wrong, but I still couldn't zip a file with an extended char in the file name and then be able to unzip it into the same file name using Windows 7...

Answer (score 2):

The standard for zip file names is UTF-8 which is apparrently ignored by many.
http://datadriven.com.au/2008/12/zip-files-and-encoding-i-hate-you/

In C++ a UTF-8 string would be retrieved as char *  and then it would need to be converted to a displayable encoding. For example UTF-16, or the current system locale.

Comment: The link posted by vulcanraven above has an updated version of the ZIP/UNZIP utils, but I'm not sure what's the issue here -- when I zip a file with a name that has an extended character and then un-ZIP it in Windows 7 that character turns into something else (looks like a Chinese symbol to me.) Is it a bug in Windows 7 or in the ZIP implementation from the link above?

Comment: It appears that Windows 7's zip tool will encode the filename in the current windows locale.  For example if I use the Japanese character 林 (which means forest) in a file name and zip it with the windows tool, it is saving it in the default windows locale (in my case Shift-JIS).
Shift-JIS:  0x97 0xD1
UTF-8:  0xE6 0x9E 0x97
UCS-2:  0x6797

Comment: Wow, that's lame. So is there some sort of an open source archiving algorithm that can do: file compression, encryption, password protection?